Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem on $L$
Am an absolute beginner here. But I've read that if a sentence $A$ is a theorem of a Theory $T$, then $T[\neg A]$ is inconsistent (where $T[\neg A]$ means that $\neg A$ is added as a logical axiom to $T$.
Now, if say some axiom $A$ were shown to be not provable in $ZF$ then $ZF+A$ is consistent and would have a model $M$... But from Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem, this is quite hard to do since we cannot construct such $M$ from $ZF$.
Now in most results about the class of constructible sets ($L$). Let $A_L$ be the axiom that all sets are constructible (i.e. $V=L$). From what I understand, we cannot prove that $L$ is not a theorem of $ZF$ given that if $ZF$ is consistent (an assumption) we also have $ZF+A_L$ as consistent as we can construct a model $L$, which is a subclass of $V$ that satisfies $ZF+A_L$ (i.e. Jech 2006)
Now, my question is, we assumed that $ZF$ is consistent and from this showed that $V$ satisfies $ZF$. Due to this assumption, we avoided Godel's 2nd Theorem. But why cant we apply Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem in constructing $L$ since we are essentially showing that $L$ is a model of $ZF+A_L$ and that $ZF+A_L$ is consistent.
My guess is that in constructing $L$, we only used the $ZF$ axioms that were assumed to be consistent, but $A_L$ is not involved ... But then again I have been wrong in many of my guesses so any help is welcome.

By definition, theorems are provable. Presumably you mean $A$ to be a sentence. But your very first sentence is incorrect. If $A$ is not provable, that does not mean adding the negation gives an inconsistent system.

@ArturoMagidin okay thanks I edited my post Sorry it was a mistype. For the first statement am referring to the Corollary in p.43 of Shoenfield "Mathematical Logic"

What you say now is very different from what you originally wrote.

Yes? I think? (I'm not sure I understand your question.) We assume ZF holds in V and then use that fact to show there's a definable subclass $L\subseteq V$ that satisfies ZF + V=L. We never proved anything consistent, but this process translates to a relative consistency proof that if ZF is consistent, so is ZF + V=L.

@spaceisdarkgreen okay thanks so in assuming that $ZF$ is consistent, we are assuming that it holds in $V$. Am just trying to check that when we defined $L$, we are not trying to "prove" that "ZF+V=L" is consistent using "ZF" since this would violate Godel's Second Incompletness theorem I guess ?

@spaceisdarkgreen going back a little further ... my question is related to my confusion with the result "A Theory $T$ is consistent iff it has a model". However, we constructed models $V$ and $L$ s.t. they satisfy $ZF$. By the result this should imply that $ZF$ is consistent. However, by Godel's Second Incompleteness Theorem, we cannot prove $ZF$ within $ZF$ so we just have to assume that $ZF$ is consistent ... and yet we have models $V$ and $L$

@LinkL Consistency is equivalent to there being a set-sized model. Did we construct $V$? Not really... we just assumed the $\sf ZF$ axioms hold in our "domain of discourse" which we're calling $V$... Now, if we were to assume further, there's a set $M\models \sf ZF$, that would be assuming $\sf Con(ZF)$, and then we could carry out the construction of the constructible universe inside $M$ to get a set $L^M\subseteq M$ such that $L^M\models \sf ZF+V=L,$ and hence conclude $\sf Con(ZF+V=L)$... but we needed to assume $\sf ZF+ Con(ZF),$ not just $\sf ZF,$ to get there.

@LinkL When we're working in $\sf ZF,$ $V$ and $L$ and other proper classes aren't really actual objects... they're just definable properties. $V$ is the boring property that everything satisfies, e.g. the formula $x=x$. $L$ is more intricate... $x\in L$ is just shorthand for "$x$ has the property (that we could write down in at length the bare language of set theory) of being constructible". Now we can relativize any sentence $\varphi$ to a sentence $\varphi^L$ that says what $\varphi$ says, only restricted to constructible sets and show $ZF\vdash \varphi^L$ for every $\varphi\in \sf ZF+V=L.$

@LinkL Then, if there were any inconsistency provable from $\sf ZF + V=L,$ we could just translate that into a proof of inconsistency in $\sf ZF,$ by using the $\varphi^L$ in place of $\varphi$ for every sentence $\varphi$ appearing in the proof. So if $\sf ZF+V=L$ is inconistent, so is $\sf ZF$... So that's a more syntactic/formal-proof-based way of seeing the relative consistency.

@spaceisdarkgreen ok thanks ! this is the clearest explanation I ever got. just one more little thing ... so when we constructed $L$, in the proof that $V=L$ is consistent with $ZF$, we held that $L$ is a set - assuming Con(ZF) ?

@LinkL Nope. When we just construct $L$ in ZF / "inside $V$", it is a proper class. (But you can use that as a template for a construction inside a set-sized model, if there is one, as remarked above.)

@spaceisdarkgreen oh okay so "inside $V$", $L$ is a proper class but if ZF is consistent then there's a set-sized model $M \models ZF$ such that "outside $V$", $L^M$ is a set ?

No, everything's inside $V$. $M$ is a set in $V.$ $L^M$ is a set in $V.$ $L$ is a proper subclass of $V$ that is not the same thing as $L^M$. $L^M = {x\in M : M\models \mbox{"$x$ is constructible"}}$, $L= {x: \mbox{"$x$ is constructible"}},$ $V = {x: x = x}$
